# Retrieve array in PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to send an `array` using *Ajax* to a script *PHP*.

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "vendas_funcoes.php",
    data: {"data": arrayItens},
    success: function(msg){
        console.log("ok");
    }
});
```

I already tried to use te example below, but it doesn't work.

**vendas_funcoes.php:**

```
<?php
    $data = stripslashes($_POST);

    // usar foreach para ler o array
    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

How do I receive this `array` im my *PHP* script to manipulate him ? Aparently the code below sends the `array` empty.

Excuse me for possible grammar mistakes, i'm brazilian.

Comment: `stripslashes` takes a string as parameter, so trying to feed it the $_POST array makes no sense to begin with. And what slashes are there that would need stripping anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP reads your POST data into the `$_POST` array, so you can retrieve your original array by reading `$_POST['data']`

**Javascript:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "vendas_funcoes.php",
    data: {"data": arrayItens},
    success: function(msg){
        console.log("ok");
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    // usar foreach para ler o array
    foreach($data as $d){
        echo $d;
    }
?>
```

Tip, if you do `print_r(arr)` or `var_dump(arr)` on  your array, you can easily see the structure of your array, and find an efficient way of manipulating it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data` is an object. You need to use `$data["data"]` to get the array.

Your actual `$data` is what you send via POST `{"data": arrayItens}`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['data']` has your data because you are sending the key as `data` in

```
data: {"data": arrayItens},
```

It's better to have some sanity checks and then process the data.

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])  && !empty($_POST['data'])){
  // business logic

}
```